# Prove that $\int_{x}^{x+ (\ln x /x)} e^{t^2} dt > \frac{e^{x^2} \ln x}{2 x}$

Tags: integration, inequality

Prove that:
$$\int_{x}^{x+ \frac{ln x}{x}} e^{t^2} dt > \frac{e^{x^2} \ln x}{2 x}$$

Is this correct?

From The Mean Value Theorem for Definite Integrals:

$$\int_{x}^{x+ \frac{\ln x}{x}} e^{t^2} dt  = \frac{\ln x}{x} e^{c^2}$$ for $c \in [x, x + \frac{\ln x}{x}]$.

Because $e^{t^2}$ is increasing we have:

$\frac{\ln x}{x} e^{c^2} \ge \frac{\ln x}{x} e^{x^2} > \frac{\ln x}{2 x} e^{x^2}$.

Comment: Did you mean to mention for $x \geq 0$? Otherwise, $e^{t^2}$ is not an increasing function everywhere ... or even better $x\geq 1$ to avoid $\ln{x}$ becoming negative?

Comment: You are right, $x \ge 1$ should have been mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As another user already mentioned, you want $x>1$, since $\ln x$ would either be undefined or less than zero otherwise. While your proof works, we do not need the mean value theorem. Simply use that $e^{t^2}$ is an increasing function for $t>0$, then
$$\int_x^{x+\frac{\ln(x)}{x}} e^{t^2} d t \geq \int_x^{x+\frac{\ln(x)}{x}} e^{x^2} d t =\frac{\ln(x)}{x}e^{x^2}>\frac{\ln(x)}{2x}e^{x^2}$$